# Terraform: Create 2 map items for each element in a loop

Tags: terraform

I am trying to loop through a list of objects and create a map from it. The thing is I need 2 items of the map for each element in the loop. Here is what I tried and I am getting syntax errors.

```
variable "id" { 
    default = "my_id" 
}

variable "name" { 
    default = "my_name"  
}

variable "configs" {
   default = [
    { id = 1, from = "value-1-from", to = "value-1-to" },
    { id = 2, from = "value-2-from", to = "value-2-to" },
    { id = 3, from = "value-3-from", to = "value-3-to" }, 
  ]
}

{ for config in var.configs: [
    "${var.name}-${config.id}" => {
      merge(
        { type = { S = "draft" } },
        { from = { S = config.from } },
        { to = { S = config.to } },
      )},
    "${var.id}-${config.id}" => {
      merge(
        { type = { S = "copy" } },
        { from = { S = config.from } },
        { to = { S = config.to } },
     )}
  ]
}
```

I different options and ended up in error as well.

Here is the working version with a single map item for each element in the loop:

```
{ for config in var.configs: 
      "${var.name}-${config.id}" => 
      merge(
        { type = { S = "draft" } },
        { from = { S = config.from } },
        { to = { S = config.to } },
      )
}
```

This is the output I need:

```
{
  "my_name-1" = {
    "from" = { "S" = "value-1-from" }
    "to" = { "S" = "value-1-to" }
    "type" = { "S" = "draft" }
  }
  "my_id-1" = {
    "from" = { "S" = "value-1-from" }
    "to" = { "S" = "value-1-to" }
    "type" = { "S" = "copy" }
  }
  "my_name-2" = {
    "from" = { "S" = "value-2-from" }
    "to" = { "S" = "value-2-to" }
    "type" = { "S" = "draft" }
  }
  "my_id-2" = {
    "from" = { "S" = "value-2-from" }
    "to" = { "S" = "value-2-to" }
    "type" = { "S" = "copy" }
  }
  "my_name-3" = {
    "from" = { "S" = "value-3-from" }
    "to" = { "S" = "value-3-to" }
    "type" = { "S" = "draft" }
  }
  "my_id-3" = {
    "from" = { "S" = "value-3-from" }
    "to" = { "S" = "value-3-to" }
    "type" = { "S" = "copy" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are always a few different approaches to do something like this, but I would go with something like this:

```
locals {
  gen = merge([for config in var.configs :
    {
      "${var.name}-${config.id}" = {
        type = { S = "draft" },
        from = { S = config.from },
        to   = { S = config.to }
      },
      "${var.id}-${config.id}" = {
        type = { S = "draft" },
        from = { S = config.from },
        to   = { S = config.to }
      }
    }
  ]...)
}
```

This creates a list of maps from the original `configs` list, where each element of the new list is a map with your required two elements. These individual maps are then merged with the `merge([]...)` call to produce a single map.

Note that I have also removed the unnecessary `merge()` calls from your example - the inner maps can be created directly without a `merge`.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Is there a way to retain the order of the items in the map (I am sure it doesn't matter for a map, but I have something up for it)

Comment: No, a map is unordered